# GNU sed and newlines with multiple scripts

Tags: sed, gnu-sed

Suppose we start with this string:

```
echo "1:apple:fruit.2:banana:fruit.3:cucumber:veggie.4:date:fruit.5:eggplant:veggie.">list.tmp
```

and want to end up with this result:

```
1-apple:fruit
2-banana:fruit
3-cucumber:veggie
4-date:fruit
5-eggplant:veggie
```

Why does this work:

```
sed -e 's/\./\n/g' -i list.tmp
sed -e 's/:/-/' list.tmp
```

But but not this:

```
sed -e 's/\./\n/g' -e 's/:/-/' list.tmp
```

The second command yields this, apparently ignoring the new newlines when looking for the first occurrence of ':' on each line.

```
1-apple:fruit
2:banana:fruit
3:cucumber:veggie
4:date:fruit
5:eggplant:veggie
```

With an extended version of the input:

```
echo "one:apple:fruit.two:banana:fruit.three:cucumber:veggie.four:date:fruit.five:eggplant:veggie.">list.tmp
```

I want to end up with this result:

```
one-apple:fruit
two-banana:fruit
three-cucumber:veggie
four-date:fruit
five-eggplant:veggie
```

Comment: You forgot the `g` modifier on the second command in the double `-e` formulation.  When the first `-e` completes, all the lines are still in the pattern space (the main working area in `sed`) — they do not become 5 separately read lines.  You read one line; you're still processing it.  Mind you, you'll probably need to use a modified pattern: `s/\([0-9]\):/\1-/g` perhaps.

Comment: You also need to be using GNU `sed`; that suggestion doesn't work in BSD (macOS) `sed`.

Comment: The part that doesn't work in BSD (macOS) `sed` is the first expression, with `\n` in the replacement part of the `s///` command.  POSIX [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) requires that you use a backslash to escape a literal newline in the replacement text: _A line can be split by substituting a `<newline>` into it. The application shall escape the `<newline>` in the replacement by preceding it by a `<backslash>`._ GNU `sed` is more flexible.  Since the question title says "GNU sed", there's no problem — except I have to remember to use it.

Comment: and just use awk anyway - `awk -v RS='.' 'sub(/:/,"-")' list.tmp` will do what you want using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring key comment into an answer.*</sup>

#### Original data

You forgot the `g` modifier on the second command in the double `-e` formulation. When the first `-e` completes, all the lines are still in the pattern space (the main working area in sed) — they do not become 5 separately read lines. You read one line; you're still processing it. Mind you, you'll need to use a modified pattern:

```
s/\([0-9]\):/\1-/g
```

Combining these, in GNU `sed` (as stipulated in the question title), you get:

```
sed -e 's/\./\n/g' -e 's/\([0-9]\):/\1-/g' list.tmp
```

Note that POSIX `sed` and other versions of `sed` have different rules about the newline substitution in the first `-e` expression.

#### Consider using `awk`

If changing tools from `sed` to `awk` is an option, you can do it more simply in `awk`, as shown by [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61035408/gnu-sed-and-newlines-with-multiple-scripts#comment107980288_61035408).  Since that solution doesn't need to change to address the revised data, it clearly has advantages — the disadvantage is that it is not using `sed`.  In 'the real world', you use the best tool for the job — and in this example, that's `awk`.

#### Extended data

With the 'extended' input, where there aren't convenient single digit numbers but you want to change the first colon on each line to a dash, you have to work harder:

```
sed -e 's/\./\n/g' \
    -e  's/^\([^:]*\):/\1-/' \
    -e 's/\(\n[^:]*\):/\1-/g' \
    list.tmp
```

- The first `-e` in unchanged.
- The second looks for a sequence of non-colons followed by a colon at the start of the pattern space and replaces it with the sequence of non-colons and a dash.  The `g` modifier is irrelevant here.
- The third `-e` looks for a newline followed by a sequence of non-colons followed by a colon, and replaces it with the newline, the non-colon sequence and a dash.   The `g` modifier is very relevant here.

You can flatten that all onto one line, but it is easier to see the similarities between the last two `-e` options if they're laid out on separate lines.

You can also experiment with ERE (extended regular expressions) with the `-E` option, and group the two separate replacements into one:

```
{
echo "1:apple:fruit.2:banana:fruit.3:cucumber:veggie.4:date:fruit.5:eggplant:veggie."
echo "one:apple:fruit.two:banana:fruit.three:cucumber:veggie.four:date:fruit.five:eggplant:veggie."
} |
sed -E -e 's/\./\
/g' -e 's/((^|\n)[^:]+):/\1-/g'
```

That yields:

```
1-apple:fruit
2-banana:fruit
3-cucumber:veggie
4-date:fruit
5-eggplant:veggie

one-apple:fruit
two-banana:fruit
three-cucumber:veggie
four-date:fruit
five-eggplant:veggie
```

If you don't want the extra blank line, remove the final newline:

```
{
echo "1:apple:fruit.2:banana:fruit.3:cucumber:veggie.4:date:fruit.5:eggplant:veggie."
echo "one:apple:fruit.two:banana:fruit.three:cucumber:veggie.four:date:fruit.five:eggplant:veggie."
} |
sed -E -e 's/\./\
/g' -e 's/((^|\n)[^:]+):/\1-/g' -e 's/\n$//'
```

The backslash-newline notation works correctly in both GNU `sed` and POSIX (including BSD and macOS) `sed`; you can re-replace that with `\n` in GNU `sed`.
The `\n` in the replacement part of the `s///` command doesn't work in BSD (macOS) `sed`. POSIX [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) requires that you use a backslash to escape a literal newline in the replacement text:

> A line can be split by substituting a `<newline>` into it. The application shall escape the `<newline>` in the replacement by preceding it by a `<backslash>`.

GNU sed is more flexible.

Also (according to [potong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/967492/potong)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61036398/15168)), there is a GNU-specific modifier `m` that you can use to do the multi-line matching in one operation.

Comment: I updated my post to clarify my question. In the double-e statement, the first statement should add newlines to the text in the pattern space. Does sed still treat the thing as one line because it went in as one line?

Comment: Yes; it is strictly one 'read operation' that ends up creating (in this case)  5 newlines in the pattern space, and the printing eventually outputs them all, plus a newline at the end (I wondered why I got a blank line after the output — now I know).  The read operation reads one line and removes the trailing newline; the printing adds back the newline that was removed. Reading the POSIX [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) manual/specification, and probably the GNU [`sed` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/), helps clarify this.

Comment: You can't go changing your example after people have provided answers!  That's not FAIR!  It's bad enough extending a question with an extra example — removing the one that was present when the answer was written is simply not allowed!

Comment: I appreciate the etiquette pointer. I am still new on SO and do not want to tick off people who are trying to help! I will mull over the gnu-specific modifier (I am rarely on non-gnu systems and am not terribly worried about portability). Thank you so much for your pointers.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'y/./\n/;s/^([^:]*):/\1-/mg' file
```

Translate all periods to newlines.

Using the GNU specific `m` or multiline flag, replace from the start of each line in the pattern space (i.e. the start of a line as indicated by `^` is either the start of a string or following a newline), any non-colon characters followed by a colon by the non-colon characters and a dash `-`. This effectively replaces the first colon in each line by a dash.